# OpenCart filter: Clear old selection

Tags: jquery, filter, opencart, opencart2.x

I've been trying to do this for a while but I don't know what to do anymore. I'm using OpenCart version 2.3.0.2 . Somehow the filter is not working correctly.

First time I select the filters it's ok. But if I remove 2 filters and add a new one, the old filters will stay in the URL.

This adds the filter id to URL:

```
$('#button-filter').on('click', function() {
    filter = [];    
    $('input[name^=\'filter\']:checked').each(function(element) {
        filter.push(this.value);
    });
    location = '<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',');
});
```

This one clears the filters id:

```
$('#button-filterclear').on('click', function() {
  filter = [];  
  $('input[name^=\'filter\']:checked').each(function(element) {
    filter.push(this.value);
  });
  location = '<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=';
});
```

I need the first button to clear, and then add the new filters id.

Answer (score 0):

As first, the clearing filters method is wrong:

```
$('#button-filterclear').on('click', function() {
    // NOT USED: filter = [];
    // NOT USED: $('input[name^=\'filter\']:checked').each(function(element) {
    // NOT USED:     filter.push(this.value);
    // NOT USED: });
    location = '<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=';
});
```

Probably the only reason why the filters selection remains is that your parent `form` element has no `autocomplete="off"`. Add the attribute and should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use on click event on links:-

Inside each click function :-

Add window.location.href=?page=1&productName=this etc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer but it's not working.

The problema is still there. Watch the url, its not removing the old query:

/index.php?route=product/category&path=59&filter=35,36,31,32

Id 35 and 36 was the first two fitler. Then I removed thoose and add 31 and 32 but the remain in the url.